# Caps Lock key not working

Tags: keyboard

The caps lock key in my MacBook Pro (mid 2015, running MacOS Sierra 10.12) is not working. When I press it, the led doesn't turn on and it has no effect. However, if I logout from my account and go back to the login screen, then it works normally, which means it is some user preference setting. (by working normally I mean the led turns on and the sign of caps lock turned on appears in the password field)

The problem is, I have no idea what kind of setting it might be. In the system preferences, under keyboard, caps lock is assigned its normal function. I do have a few apps for remapping system input: Karabiner, BetterTouchTool and USB Overdrive, but I don't have any setting involving caps lock in any of them.

Comment: Do you use any non Latin keyboards?  In sierra caps lock can be set to switch between Latin and non Latin.  Also I have heard karabiner can cause your problem.

Comment: Turns out it was a bug in Karabiner-Elements. The developer is aware of it but still has no fix. Please repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand this problem is often caused by Karabiner Elements.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you having problems with the caps lock not working on a bluetooth keyboard connection, I have the following suggestion. First, go to bluetooth in System Preferences and delete keyboard entirely. Now setup bluetooth keyboard ONLY through Keyboard in SP by SET UP KEYBOARD next to Modifier Keys. It helps to have the virtual keyboard visible. Wait until keyboard is recognized through this process. Repeat procedure if the keyboard isn't recognized. It will eventually connect and your Caps Lock will be functional on both the virtual and bluetooth keyboards.Simple but it worked flawlessly for me.